# How to show remote image uri file in React-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to load an image in React-native by making use of `<Image source={{}}` with styling but the image does not show on the screen(Making use of Genymotion Emulator)

Dependencies are as follows;

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
},
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        Hello world
</Text>
      <Image source={{ uri: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg' }}
        style={styles.img}

      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "darkslateblue",
    fontSize: 30
  },
  img: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100 / 2,
  },
})
export default App
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe try to listen to `onError` and see if it outputs some error.

Comment: @ClaudiusDan  It didn't register any Error

Comment: Set the resize mode?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be the problem of your code, as it works for me on iOS simualtor and android simulator.
I never use Genymotion Emulator but you should check that first.

[image]